# setInterval works online on same sytem (with 2 browsers open) but not online on separate systems

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a setinterval code updating a div. This works fine when tested in two separate browsers on the same system but when I test online on say a separate mac and PC and it stops.

The code is as follows:-

Javascript:

```
    function setupAjaxIntervalDiscuss(){
    setInterval(function()
    {
    var datastring = 'refreshchat=true&projid=' + proj_id + '&uid=' + uid;
    ajaxUpdateDiscussion(datastring);
    }, 2000);
    }

   function ajaxUpdateDiscussion(ajaxdata){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uploaddata.php",
        data: ajaxdata,
        success: function(data){
        $("#discussresult").html(data);
        refreshNav();//Updating a scrollbar styled with JS
                    }
        });
  }
```

PHP(this update correctly just here for ref) :

```
 if(isset($_POST["refreshchat"])){
 $user_id= $_POST['uid'];
 $proj_id=$_POST['projid'];
 echo '<img class="closeddiscuss" src="images/closey.png" title="close" alt="close"/>'; 
  $get_discuss_query = "SELECT * FROM discuss INNER JOIN user ON discuss.user_id=user.user_id
                        WHERE discuss.project_id=$proj_id ORDER BY discuss_id DESC";
                        $get_discuss_result=mysql_query($get_discuss_query);
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_discuss_result)){
                        $text = nl2br($row['discuss_text']);
                        $name = $row['user_name'];
                        $user_profileimageurl = $row['user_profileimageurl'];
                        echo '<div class="discussbubble"><p>'.$text.'</p><img class="smallprofileimage" src="'.$user_profileimageurl.'" alt="user profile image"/> by '.$name.'</div>';
                        }
   }
```

Comment: Does it work at all on the new, added system? If not, what errors do you see in the console?

Comment: just setting firebug on another system console is giving no errors on the mac. Just give it a while on pc

Comment: no errors the interval is firing AJAX fine. But the page contents are just not updating very odd. The update only comes on a post which i update somewhere else as a bog standard way of doing it

Comment: Could you set this up somewhere online, where we can see it in action?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the page isn't updating. Maybe it's cached? Try:

```
function ajaxUpdateDiscussion(ajaxdata){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uploaddata.php?t=" + Math.random(),
        data: ajaxdata,
        success: function(data){
        $("#discussresult").html(data);
        refreshNav();//Updating a scrollbar styled with JS
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

since you say it update success once so i think you use ie to test------
try this?

```
function setupAjaxIntervalDiscuss(){
    setInterval(function(){
        ajaxUpdateDiscussion({
            refreshchat:true,
            projid:proj_id,
            uid:uid,
            rand:Math.random()
        });
    }, 2000);
}

function ajaxUpdateDiscussion(ajaxdata){
    $.post( "uploaddata.php", ajaxdata, function  ( data ) {
        $("#discussresult").html(data);
        refreshNav();//Updating a scrollbar styled with JS
    })
}
```

or you use the same uid to test so see session controls